# position() function is not working XSLT2.0 FOP2.8

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I am trying to fetch the data from xml based upon the position below is the sample xml

```
<node>
  <Item>
    <ItemName><![CDATA[Name]]></ItemName>
    <ItemValue><![CDATA[Value]]></ItemValue>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemName><![CDATA[Name]]></ItemName>
    <ItemValue><![CDATA[Value]]></ItemValue>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemName><![CDATA[Name]]></ItemName>
    <ItemValue><![CDATA[Value3]]></ItemValue>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemName><![CDATA[Name]]></ItemName>
    <ItemValue><![CDATA[Value4]]></ItemValue>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <ItemName><![CDATA[Name]]></ItemName>
   <ItemValue><![CDATA[Value]]></ItemValue>
  </Item>
</node>
```

Now I want to get that value3 and value4 to be fetched and concatenated based upon the position

This is my sample logic in xslt for the same;

```
 <xsl:for-each select="node/Item">
     <xsl:variable name="cellValue">
        <xsl:if test="(ItemValue != '')">
           <xsl:when test ="position() = 4"/> <!--will skip as it is getting concatenated with pos() 3-->
           <xsl:when test ="position() = 3">
             <xsl:value-of select="concat(ItemValue,node/Item[position()+1]/ItemValue)"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:value-of select="ItemValue"/>
           </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="$cellValue != ''">
     <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
         <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="$cellValue"/>
         </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
     </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:if>
    
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Name space i am using

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
                xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions"
                xmlns:pre="xalan://org.apache.xalan.Version"
                xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

But I am seeing that  value3 and value4 is not getting populated in my output pdf

****Update****

Sorry for being inconvenient:

Updated the xml hierarchy format

[Unfortunately you haven't explained what your code is supposed to do..]

**Here I am trying to get the values from elements matching xpath:

```
node/Item/ItemValue
```

ItemValue (s) are not static; only assurity is that for the index 3 and 4; which are Item[3] and Item[4]; we always need to concatenate these ItemValue (s). And rest ItemValues can be as it is.
Hence I was using position() function to evaluate the positions of each

```
node/Item
```

what will be the possible solution then?

[You seem to have misunderstood what the position() function does.]

**If possible can you please give a brief idea about the use case of position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `following-sibling::*[1]` axis like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="cellValue">
  <xsl:if test="(ItemValue != '')">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test ="position() = 4"/> <!--will skip as it is getting concatenated with pos() 3-->
      <xsl:when test ="position() = 3">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(ItemValue,  following-sibling::Item[1]/ItemValue)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="ItemValue"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

the predicate `[1]` means only the first

Comment: but that will concat 3rd ItemValue and the first item value (as per my understanding ,as when test we are doing for pos 3); so in that case <xsl:value-of select="concat(ItemValue,  following-sibling::Item[4]/ItemValue)"/> will it suffice to concat 3rd and 4th item value from xml?

Comment: `following-sibling::Item[1]` means the first following-sibling=what you want
`following-sibling::Item[4]` means the forth following-sibling=not what you want. 
Just give it a try.

Comment: had tried but still same nothing is coming in my pdf

Comment: Did you also correct the missing choose?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood what the position() function does.

Unfortunately you haven't explained what your code is supposed to do, and it's hard to reverse engineer your requirements from code that doesn't meet them.

You include the code fragment `node/Item[position()+1]`. This won't select anything. Firstly, the context is an `Item` element, and your `Item` element does not have a child called `node`. Perhaps you meant `parent::node`. Secondly a numeric predicate P is short for `[position()=P]`, so your predicate means `[position()=position()+1]` which will never be true. Perhaps you meant `following-sibling::Item`.

Comment: I have updated the question; it will be helpful if you can check the same

Comment: @RitoSarkar has given you a good answer.

Comment: had tried the suggested solution from above answer but unfortunately this is not happening